# To assign onclick event to multiple buttons

Tags: javascript, button, onclick

I am working on a code to generate multiple buttons depending on user input

```
    for(var loop = 0; loop < up.length ; loop++){
document.write('<button style="background-color:'+ up[loop] +';width:100;height:100" </button>');

}
```

however I want to have same onclick function for every button,but if I use like the one below, the function doesn't gets executed . What's the problem and where am I going wrong? Please help.

```
document.write('<button style="background-color:'+ up[loop] +';width:100;height:100" onclick= "myfn()" </button>');
```

Comment: Valid HTML is a prerequisite to get anything working, and using some sort of DOM insertion instead of document.write is always a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what about something like this (no jquery needed and no document.write):

```
var button;
for (i=0; i<5; i++) {
    button = document.createElement('button');
    button.innerHTML = "button - " + i;
    button.addEventListener('click', myFn);
    document.body.appendChild(button);
}


function myFn() {
    alert('button clicked');
}
```

see here: http://jsfiddle.net/yNFqy/1/

Comment: It worked! thanks,but how can I modify the look and feel of the button using css?

Comment: Yes, you can add a line there:  button.classList.add('your-classname-here') and then style it w/ CSS

Comment: well, my function myFn() needs element at 'i' th position,like up[i],how can I pass an argument to myFn() here?

Answer (score 1):

Typo, you don't close your opening tag:

```
 document.write('<button style="background-color:'+ up[loop] +';width:100;height:100" onclick="myfn()"></button>');
```

Always make sure you validate with the W3c markup validation service: http://validator.w3.org

You should also investigate unobtrusively attaching event handlers, writing handlers inline isn't ideal.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use jQuery
2. Add a class to the buttons (always the same class)
3. User jQuery's click method to handle the click

> $('.class-name).click(function() {   alert("click"); });